Redirect to an error page if query is not matched in Node+Express+MongoDB
I am developing a website form that will access information stored in a MongoDB database (imagine accessing a library catalog). To do so, I am using NodeJS, Express, MongoDB and views with EJS.
The code is working fine, but I would like to display an error page or something like that if no results are found. I have been trying for a while, but my code doesn't seem to work.
This is what I did so far. The full code is quite long, so I will paste only the relevant part in my index.js file:
//The querying code works, and the following two lines print the results in a view called "queryResult".
//filteredData is a filter I used to arrange the information in order.

    const libraryItems = await collection.aggregate(filteredData).toArray() 
       res.render("queryResult", {libraryItems : libraryItems})
    if(libraryItems == null){
      res.render("noResults") //I created a view called noResults.ejs in the folder "views"
      return
      }
    })

With this code, when a query is not successful, I get the view "queryResult" with an empty list of items. What I expect is to get the view "noResults" with a message informing the user that no results were found.
I think the solution must be quite simple, but I am not very experienced in coding, so I am not sure about how to solve it. Any help will be greatly apreciated.

You've said " when a query is not successful, I get the view "queryResult" with an empty list of items" but then you test with null: libraryItems == null; instead of libraryItems == []. Also, that check should be done before any render step.

I understand your point about checking before rendering. Thank you, I think that might be the main issue. I don't know how to do it, but I will try to find out.

You are rendering before if statement. You need to check first the count of the array with libraryItems.length and use it inside if statement.

You need to check the count of the items returned. And as I see, you are sending the render with result before checking it.
const libraryItems = await collection.aggregate(filteredData).toArray()
const libraryItems_count = libraryItems.length;

if(!libraryItems || libraryItems == null || libraryItems_count < 1){
  res.render("noResults")
  return;
}

res.render("queryResult", {libraryItems : libraryItems});


Great! I didn't think about counting the items of the array. Many thanks!

You are welcome! Just to remind, when you type res.render() to anywhere in your code, you won't be able to send it again.
